# Latitude/Longitude conversion

Tags: c++, matlab

i have 64 bit as lat/long (32 bit lat , 32 bit long),  i don't know its originally format (and type) but i know its position on google map. i extract lat long as below:

```
lat=uint32*180/2^31
long=uint32*180/2^31
```

but when i see lat long on the google map i have many degree error in lat long.
how can i convert it with no error?
does any one know this lat long format (or type)?

Comment: `2^31` probably doesn't do what you think it does. What are you expecting there?

Comment: And what does the _bitwise XOR_ [arithmetic operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic) has to do with that?

Comment: BTW, to divide by a power of two, you can use the right shift `operator >>`.

Comment: Are you even sure its truly integer and not two 32 bit float lon/lat values?  As an experiment, try (temporarily) reinterpret_cast-ing each (upper and lower) to a float.  What do you get?

Answer (score 1):

In other languages `^` is the exponent operator but not in C/C++.  What you're looking for is probably the bit-shift operators `<<` and `>>`.  `1 << 31` means "number 1 bit-shifted 31 places left" which is equal to 2 raised to the 32nd power (which you might write as 2^32 in some languages - not C/C++).

The exact answer is going to depend on exact details of your platform and the input value - particularly whether each are big endian or little endian.  But it's going to involve something like this:

```
  /* A 64-bit input value encoding two 32-bit components */
  unsigned long int foo = 64424509440 + 19;
  /* Extracting two 32-bit components */
  cout << foo << " " << ( foo >> 32 ) << " " << ( foo & ( (1 << 31) - 1 ) ) << endl;
```